# installing manjaro on usb with rufus

Tags: linux, dual-boot, manjaro

i just tried to dual boot manjaro with windows 10. I downloaded 'manjaro-kde-21.0.7-210614-linux510' from manjaro website and tried to install it on USB via rufus with these settings:

```
Partition scheme --> MBR
Target system --> BIOS or UEFI
File System --> FAT32
cluster size --> 4096 bytes
```

but I get:

```
Error: write error.
```

I tried installing ubuntu 21.04 LTS with the same settings, it worked fine.
It is worth mentioning that I tried installing another edition of manjaro(xfce), and again I got write error.

I would appreciate any help on this. thanks a lot.

Comment: Your error is happening using a tool running in Windows. This site is about providing solutions using Unix/Linux not using Windows. Consider asking this question on https://superuser.com/ instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question deals with a tool run in Windows, not Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Run a bad blocks check for your USB, which you can do by clicking *Show advanced format options* in Rufus and then *Check device for bad blocks*. Chances are that, if you are getting a write error, your USB drive is defective, as it is very common for flash based drives to fail after a while. And yes, different images can produce different results with a defective drive, since no two images are the same size.

Also, whenever you have an error in Rufus, you should check what its log tells you by clicking the small log button (located at the left of the `START` button) or by pressing `Ctrl`-`L`.